# Sweetalert2 confirmButton stays visible when selectize.js opens - independent of z-index

Tags: z-index, selectize.js, sweetalert2

I have a sweetalert2 like this:

[image]

When I want to pick something it looks like that:

[image]

My code inside the sweetalert2 is:

```
<div className={'col-12 course-item-modal'}>
            <div className="row">

                <div className="form-group col-12">
                    <div className="row">
                        <label htmlFor="form_4_course">Kurs</label>
                        <select id="form_4_course" name="form[4][course]" className="selectize form-control">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="60"> GTS</option>
                            <option value="62">Sprechstunde</option>
                            <option value="59">BesF 1c</option>
                            <option value="58">BesF 3c</option>
                            <option value="53" selected="selected">D 1a</option>
                            <option value="56">D 1b</option>
                            <option value="57">W T/X 1a</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group col-12">
                    <div className="row">
                        <label className="" htmlFor="form_4_rooms">Räume</label>
                        <select id="form_4_rooms" name="form[4][rooms][]" className="selectize form-control"
                                multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="1">Info I</option>
                            <option value="2">Info I</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I use selectize.js in this react.js application.

I played around with z-index of the sweetalert2 .swal2-actions and the . 
Also I increased the z-index of the selectize containers. I tried everything possible with z-index - I guess. Nothing works at all.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
.swal2-content {
  z-index: 2 !important;
}
```

The z-index for swal2-header, swal2-body, swal2-actions and swal2-footer are 1. 
So setting the swal2-content class to z-index: 1 !important; solves the problem.